# How to use the eBay Browse API just to search for products via one server

Tags: ebay-api

I try to migrate from eBay Finding API to Browse API. My technical setting is quiet easy:

A Server searches the Browse API to find products by a keyword. Thats it.

Does anybody know if I need to implement OAuth, a redirection page for eBay-Users to log in etc.? I don't need all those features..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browse API with the `client credential flow` that mints the `Application access token`.

> Application tokens are general-use tokens that give access to interfaces that return application data. For example, many GET requests require only an Application token for authorization.

[See Documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html)

The client credential flow does not require a User to Login via eBay and the redirect etc. However, you can only use the "GET" methods like getItem, getItemByLegacyId or search for example.

If you using NodeJs or Browser you can checkout the "Get Item" example [here](https://hendt.github.io/ebay-api/). (The library will get the Application access token automatically and return the result.)